# Adding DBfailonerror in access vb creates compile error invalid use of property

Tags: ms-access, vba

An import sub that has been created in access works OK but when DBfailonerror is added a compile error invalid use of property is encountered when the sub is run from the vb editor.

Any advice re: this would be most appreciated.  Code is as follows:

```
Sub Importcl()

'DATA DECLARATIONS
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim t As TextStream
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim Cnr As String
Dim Cnri As String
Dim Cnrii As String
Dim Cnriii As String
Dim Sqlstr As String
Dim Db As DAO.Database


'SET COUNTERS TO ZERO
Cnr = 0
Cnri = 0
Cnrii = 0
Cnriii = 0

'Point to DB
Set Db = CurrentDb()

'SET TXT FILE PATH
strFilePath = "C:\Users\Vlad\CSV import\EV WORK\Book1.txt"


'ERROR HANLDER FOR TXT FILE PATH AND COUNTING OF TXT FILE LINE ITEMS
If fso.FileExists(strFilePath) Then
Set t = fso.OpenTextFile(strFilePath, ForReading, False)
    Do While t.AtEndOfStream <> True
        t.SkipLine
        Cnr = Cnr + 1
    Loop
        t.Close
Else: MsgBox ("Txt File not Found - Check File Path")
Exit Sub
End If

'DISPLAY LINE RECORDS COUNTED IN TXT FILE TO BE ADDED TO TABLE
Debug.Print Cntr; " Incl header"
MsgBox (Cnr - 1 & " records to be added")

'COUNT & DISPLAY CURRENT RECORD COUNT IN TARGET TABLE
Cnri = DCount("[Case Date]", "All Caseload Data New")


If MsgBox(Cnri & " -Current Records in table- All Caseload Data New - Continue
with Import?", vbYesNo, "Import") = vbYes Then
Db.Execute _
"INSERT INTO [All Caseload Data New] SELECT * FROM[Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes;
DATABASE=C:\Users\Dev\CSV import\DEV WORK\].[Book1#txt];"
dbFailOnError
Db.TableDefs.Refresh
Else: Exit Sub

End If

Cnrii = DCount("[Case Date]", "All Caseload Data New")

Cnriii = Cnrii - Cnri

MsgBox (Cnriii & " New records added to table All Caseload Data New")


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

With this code to start ...

```vb
Dim db As DAO.database
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT INTO tblFoo (some_text) VALUES ('bar');"
Set db = CurrentDb
```

Then these 2 `Execute` statements ..

```vb
db.Execute strInsert
dbFailOnError ' triggers error
db.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError ' compiles without error
```

Include `dbFailOnError` on the same line as `Execute`.  Placing `dbFailOnError` on a separate line triggers that *"invalid use of property"* compile error.